# extra byte in network stream

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an .net application with 2 processes, communicating using a network stream.
The protocol consists of a set of commands, some with parameters, which are sent through the stream to the server. The server processes the command, and sends a response.

The protocol for one of the commands looks like this:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte
stream.WriteByte(CmdId)
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bufferSize)
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
stream.Write(buffer, offset, bufferSize)
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(singleValue1)
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(singleValue2)
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue1)
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue2)
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

So basically I'm sending a large chunk of bytes (the length varies, but it is in the thousands), followed by 2 singles, and 2 integers).
On the receiving end, I have:

```
Dim bytes(3) As Byte
cmd = stream.readByte()
stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)
Dim bufferSize As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)
Dim buf(bufferSize - 1) As Byte
Dim nRead As Integer = 0
While nRead < bufferSize
  nRead += stream.Read(buf, nRead, bufferSize - nRead)
End While
stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)
Dim s1 As Single = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)
Dim s2 As Single = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)
Dim i1 As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)
stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)
Dim i2 As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)
```

Usually, this works fine. Very rarely (probably once every few millions of calls), The reading side gets the wrong values. I added code to trace the values sent and received. This shows that occasionally, the reading side gets two extra bytes, with the value 0, which was not sent by the writing side. These extra bytes appear in different places, e.g. in one case they were between i1 and i2; in another they were between the first and second byte of s2.

Does anyone have any idea where these 2 bytes could come from? I checked my code, and every place that writes to the stream is traced, so it doesn't look like they are actually written to the stream. It might be worth noting that s1 is always 0, in the current implementation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create an object that will store all your information and then serialize/deserialize it? You may find you avoid these types of issues.

Comment: @Phil I agree entirely - there's crazy fools like me that spend a **lot** of time writing very complex serialization code so that most folks don't have to. But sometimes you don't get to choose the format ;p

Comment: @Marc You're right of course. I assumed, since he has the code for both read and write, that he could change the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you do a `stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4)` you are failing to check the result code. It would be rare to always have enough data to fill the 4 bytes. Refactor that into a "read me 4 bytes" method that does it properly, checking (loop) that 4 bytes have been read.

Actually, I find it odd that you do this *correctly* when filling the buffer, but not when reading the ints / single. For example you could have (in C# terms)

```
static void Read(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    int read;
    while(count > 0 && (read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0) {
        count -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
    if(count > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
```

then

```
Read(stream, bytes, 0, 4)
Dim s1 As Single = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
```

etc

Comment: The reason I do it for the buffer is that it contains a lot of bytes, and they are never sent all at once.
It didn't occur to me that 4 bytes might not all be sent, but I think you are probably right.